How does the ReLU function introduce non-linearity into Neural Networks?
Can anyone explain how the ReLU function introduces non-linearity into a neural network? I've been told it does, but the outputs of $f(a) = max(0, a)$ seem either like the neuron is 'inactive' (i.e. $f(x) = 0$) or that the neuron follows a linear output (i.e. $f(x) = x, x>0$). Could someone demonstrate how an input $$x = (x_1, x_2, ... , x_n)$$ could be made non-linear by solely using ReLU activation functions?

It is a nonlinear function, so it introduces nonlinearity into the function compositions.

You can have a look here https://medium.com/@maximlopin/why-is-relu-non-linear-aa46d2bad518
